# Access Keycloak group attributes from Nodejs

Tags: keycloak

I've got Keycloak setup and running with NodeJS.

I see you can create groups and assign attributes to those groups. Is it possible to access these attributes from the NodeJS application?

I can't even find the groups let alone their attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. But there is almost no official documentation on how to achieve this. You can return most keycloak attributes, groups and roles through the client mappers. By default none are configured. 
To configure extra mappers: In the administration console, select the client and then the Mappers tab. That should bring you to a list of mappers.

[image: List of client mappers]

You can add mappers here of different types. Once you add a mapper you can decide which calls to Keycloak from the client return the attribute(s), and what the name of the returned attribute is. The following screenshot includes a mapper that returns a dictionary of groups, with subgroups, separated by forward slashes. Your Node code will need to parse the returned JSON object.

[image: group mapper details]

All the information is returned in the keycloak token, which is a Javascript Web Token. In Node you can examine it by printing the token to the log. The keycloak-connect middleware stores tokens etc in an object on the request called kauth. The path to retrieve a list of groups specified by the configuration in the above screenshot is shown below. If you change the token claim name in the configuration, you will need to change the path in your NodeJS code accordingly. You will need to logout from your application and login again for changes to the mapper to work.

```
router.get('/', async function(req, res){ 
  console.log(req.kauth.grant.access_token.content.groups) ..
}
```